# Qt: How to add custom menu items in Application Menu in Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmenu, qmenubar

I want to add a submenu in the application menu in Mac. The Application Menu already contains item "About myapp", "Quit myapp", etc. I want to add here a sub menu like **"Themes"** and then provide actions inside it like: **"Theme 1"**, **"Theme 2"**, etc.

So it should be like:

```
Menu Myapp->
    Themes->
        Theme 1
        Theme 2
```

Comment: To me it seems that this is not supported in a convenient way. While you can call setMenuRole(QAction::ApplicationSpecificRole) for QAction objects this method doesn't exist for QMenu. Probably you have to create the whole menu structure on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Main menu is your already existing menu. You can add a submenu with the following code

```
QMenu* mainMenu = new QMenu( "Menu" );

QMenu* themesMenu = new QMenu( "Themes" );
mainMenu->addMenu( themesMenu );

themesMenu->addAction( "Theme 1" );
themesMenu->addAction( "Theme 2" );
```

But I think you want to add some other input arguments to the `addAction( ... )` function, such add the slot what shall be executed on the menu activating. [Read this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-3) about this function.

[image]